# Why is a function defined to have only a single value at a point?

Tags: functions

I'm aware people have asked why a function cannot have more than one value before, on this site and on others, but I found none of the answers satisfactory, which mostly seemed to amount to "because it's defined that way", and did not discuss the reason for this definition. I do not understand the rationale behind this definition, it just seems to me a strange constraint on what otherwise was a very general notion of a "mathematical transform".

An argument could be raised that, under the accepted definition, certain properties we can conveniently say are true for all functions, won't be true for all functions under the alternative definition. For example,
$$\forall x,y.x=y\implies f(x)=f(y) \text{ for any function }f$$
But consider the converse of this same statement,
$$\forall x,y. f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y\text{ for any }\textbf{injective}\text{ function }f$$

We're already used to saying that some properties hold only for certain kinds of functions; it isn't too far a stretch to then assign a category to the functions which can produce only a single value, and say the first statement holds true for all functions of that category.

Is there then a logical reason for this special constraint or is it just this way due to convention or historical reasons?

Comment: One of the reasons we require a *unique* image for *every* element of the domain is that we do not want any confusion when dealing with the function. Think like you are assigning roll numbers to a batch of students. What will happen if two (or more) students have the same roll number or one of the students is not assigned any roll number? Will the functioning be "nice"?

Comment: I'm not sure that analogy works. This is a case where the problem is most suitably represented with a bijective function. But often we have cases where we indeed have a function where not all members of the codomain are mapped to, like some students not receiving a roll number (non-surjective functions). Similarly, it's worthwhile to consider cases where there can be multiple outputs for a given input, e.g. the roots of a polynomial or the equation of a circle.

Comment: Considering that there are many different well-defined mathematical objects generalizing functions (multi-valued functions, relations, random variables, morphisms, etc.), all of which are actively studied, I think the fact that a function is defined one way is a perfectly good reason to continue defining it that way—a function means a function, and not one of the other things with different names. As to why it's so much more prevalent than those other definitions, that's a question with many different answers that can't be boiled down to "history."

Comment: What might be gained by broadening the definition of a function in this way? Are there any advantages you can think of? Would doing so give us any new insights or abilities we don't already have? Are there already mathematical objects and structures that do the things that these new functions would do?

Comment: The "old" concept of a function has proven to be incredibly useful. As you say, we already distinguish between different types of functions. Why object to the current distinction between functions and other "transforms". We could redefine the Natural numbers to include $0$ and negatives, and then amend our language to distinguish between positive Naturals and the others, but would doing so be useful?

Answer (score 2):

There are many "transforms" from one set to another, if you think of a transform as just a set of pairs $(x,y)$.

One of the most useful transforms is the one that corresponds to the intuitive idea that you have some kind of a "rule" that tells you an element of the codomain whenever you're given an element of the domain. The cost of a load of coal depends on the number of tons you buy. The distance you travel at a fixed speed depends on how long you drive. The position of a satellite in  orbit around the Earth depends on [some set of inputs].  In each case the input determines just a single answer. It's that idea that mathematicians have codified in the abstract definition of a function.

If you changed the definition of a function to include "multi-valued functions" no actual mathematical facts would change. But many of the most common and useful statements about functions would have to start

> If $f$ is a function [that is single valued] then ...

which would complicate exposition.

The accepted definition is not

> a strange constraint on what otherwise was a very general notion of
> a "mathematical transform".

It's the choice we've made precisely because it makes dealing with the most common situation easiest.